# How to create form in HTML?

Tags: html, forms

I want to create special form using only HTML. It has text "Name" at the top and a field where you need to put the text.

```html
<form action="#">
  <p>Name<br/>
    <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
</form>
```

So I wanna have opportunity to write text in the field by clicking on the text above the field("Name").

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Answer (score 4):

Use `label` with a `for` attribute which has the value of the input `id`

```html
<form action="#">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here label `for` attribute value points to `name` attribute of a text field.
 When you click on label it will search for text field with attribute `name=name` then cursor will place on that field.

```
<form action="#">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" >
</form>
```